# LSTM activation function for monotonic input data

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, activation-function, relu

If I am using an `LSTM` to predict future values of a time series chart which is more or less monotonically increasing. Does `tanh` work as an activation function for all the `LSTM` units since it is a bounded function? or would `relu` be the right function here?

(P.S. I tried `relu` but the training loss is unstable and exploding)

Comment: How about normalizing your inputs and denorming the outputs such that the network only sees values in the range [0,1]? This is a fairly standard approach to obtain good results with all sorts of neural networks.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing however since validation and testing data should be unseen they are independently scaled on the training scaler. Therefore I could have values such as 1.01, 1.2, etc... just because the input data is monotonically increasing

Comment: Sure, I don't know what the domain of your problem is but you can always select the reasonable minimum and maximum values you'd expect to see and use those to scale rather than the exact min and max of your training data?

Comment: @DerekG Thanks. Does this mean that `Relu` is the appropriate activation function for monotonic data? or can `tanh` work as well? from your experience.

Comment: I recommend sticking to the activation functions used by the LSTM out-of-box (some sigmoids and some tanhs) rather than setting all of them to a specific type since the combination of activation functions was intelligently selected by the original authors to provide some stability and performance properties. In my experience intelligent scaling of the inputs and outputs as well as "state representation" (i.e. what information is passed to the network) are the best bets in terms of improving model convergence and performance.

Comment: One method I can think of is scaling relative to some sufficiently large and small max and min such that no value will fall outside of this range in either testing or validation set. Another solution is to normalize with respect to a running mean and also passing the running mean as an input. Can't tell you what will work best, but these are things I would try